# NN: Can I split the training set into 2 halves, and train on each half during separate epochs?

Tags: neural-networks, dataset

When training a neural network, do I get the same results in both the following cases?

- Training on half the training data for 1 epoch, then on the other half for another epoch.
- Training on the entire training data for 1 epoch.

I am training a model on variable-length sequential data. The model is already well-tuned. I would like to divide the data in subsets of different sizes to optimize the training speed (i.e.: spend less time training on padding data). If the 2 cases above are equivalent the solution is straightforward.

I can share information about the particular model, but think it should be possible to give a theoretical answer which generalizes to any model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing "epochs" and "mini-batches", so I will start by clarifying these terms:

**Mini-batch** is a batch of data that is passed together through the network at each step of the stochastic gradient descent (SGD). Data in a mini-batch need to be aligned, i.e. padded to the same length. The training set is usually divided into many mini-batches.

**Epoch** is a period of training during which every training sample is used once. That means we used all the mini-batches that we divided the training set into. Usually, at the beginning of each epoch the mini-batches are reshuffled.

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if it is the same to split the dataset into two halves and then first evaluate mini-batches from the first half and then mini-batches from the other half<sup>1</sup> as if you trained on the mini-batches from both halves simultaneously. This is obviously *exactly same* only if the mini-batches and their order is the same. If the mini-batches are interleaved between the two halves, the result will not be exactly the same (but may be *qualitatively same*, e.g. reaching the same generalization error in the end)

**However, note that this is not necessary for the padding purposes; there you only need to make sure that you group long sequences together within mini-batches. This is common approach.**

<sup>1</sup> Note that generally these two parts together form one epoch.

Comment: Very good (+1). Question: you say that "[..] you only need to make sure that you group long sequences together within mini-batches." How do you make sure that the `fit` method chooses batches of the same length (or similar lengths)? I'm tired of having to patch all my sequences to the length of the longest sequence when I use RNNs in Keras. If you prefer we can talk about this in chat or I can post a question to SO.

Comment: In this case you need to write your own generator which takes care of appropriate grouping and padding and use `fit_generator` instead.

Comment: Ok, I created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74091/keras-fit-generator), let me know if you have time to join today. Thanks PS it's a SO chat room of course ;-)